# URLRewrite in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I am planning to develop an Intranet application (Java client, JSP, SQLite)

Goal of this is that when a user clicks on the link, if the user has access (to a team which is handled in the business logic)  a file should be provided for download

There is a table in the db which holds the info and below is the example row

```
ID | file                               | team   | md5
1  | D:\test\output_20140915_100012.zip | Falcon | 5cceaf4cc400fd8f5c7fb4b2af754f4093369f59
```

where MD5 is the MD% checksum of the string "D:\test\output.zip" and not the file itself

I create the MD5 just for the sake of having random number. Reason I don't use RAND is to avoid collision (this part is trivial)

I want my URL to look like this

```
http://mywebserver:8080/<appname>/5cceaf4cc400fd8f5c7fb4b2af754f4093369f59
```

Which should be taken to

```
http://mywebserver:8080/<appname>/download.jsp?id=5cceaf4cc400fd8f5c7fb4b2af754f4093369f59
```

I am using Tomcat and I am wondering if how we could have a URL rewrite for this scenario

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to do that at the web server level (i.e. Apache, nginx)?  It'd be simpler.

Comment: @Makoto do you mean redirecting?

Comment: I don't know why you'd do this with the web server. This is much better handled in the application via a router. E.g. Spring's `@PathVariable` http://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-mvc-requestmapping-annotation-example-with-controller-methods-headers-params-requestparam-pathvariable

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend to do it with Apache HTTP Server or another server. But if you want to do it only with Tomcat 7 use [Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/):

> A Java Web Filter for any compliant web application servers (such as
>   Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty or Resin), which allows you to rewrite URLs
>   before they get to your code. It is a very powerful tool just like
>   Apache's mod_rewrite.

This filter allows you to define rules like:

> **Clean a url**
>
> ```
> <rule>
>     <from>/products/([0-9]+)</from>
>     <to>/products/index.jsp?product_id=$1</to> 
> </rule>
> ```
>
> eg, /products/1234 will be passed on to
>   /products/index.jsp?product_id=1234 without the user  noticing

from [Tuckey urlrewrite example](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/urlrewrite.xml)

Since Tomcat 8 you can use the rewrite valve.

> The rewrite valve implements URL rewrite functionality in a way that
>   is very similar to mod_rewrite from Apache HTTP Server.

[Rewrite Valve docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html)

Comment: We use only Tomcat and hence I am asking for in Tomcat 7

Comment: Well, the original question before the edit did not mention tomcat version. In that case try with tuckey   UrlRewriteFilter http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/  Later, I 'll edit my answer

Comment: Well after noticing your link only then I realized that I haven't mentioned the Tomcat version. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

For Tomcat 7 you can also use [tuckey](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) . Tucket is a Java Web Filter for any compliant web application servers and allows mod_rewrite just like Apache