# How do I install a servlet in a tomcat container and have it loaded into each web app's context?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, classloader

I'm currently using Tomcat 7.
I want to deploy/install a servlet that will be loaded in each webapp in their context.  I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve me adding the servlet to each webapp's war. Is this possible?

Ultimately, I want it to service requests on a common subpath of each webapp's context root.

- http://host/webappA/common/
- http://host/webappB/common/

I was thinking maybe I could load an annotated servlet from the tomcat common classloader, but I couldn't get that to work.  For example, same annotated servlet worked in the war, but not in the common classloader.

```
@WebServlet(
    description = "Says Hello", 
    urlPatterns = { "/HelloServlet" })
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // log hello
    }
}
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Make a third app to share the servlet to both ;)

Comment: @StefanLindenberg can you expand upon your comment? I'm not aware of how an app can provide a servlet within the context of another webapp.  Maybe provide it as an answer...

Comment: If you just want to make your servlet available under several paths, you might install redirects to its actual (and only) location.

Comment: What are you 'actually' trying to archive?

Comment: @f_puras I want to make my servlet available under several contexts, but the same subpath "common" underneath those contexts. How could I install redirects to accomplish this?

Comment: You could use a separate (Apache) webserver to do the trick: Requests to `/webappA/...` will be routed to the Tomcat instance unchanged, whereas calls to any `/webappB/...` will be transformed to `/webappA/...`, using e.g. [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html). So your servlet - and with it, your whole webapp - would be available under both contexts.Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: @f_puras, that is along the lines of what I want to accomplish, but I only have control over the Tomcat container in my environment, and I do not control the wars.  I'm the middle man, so that is why I am looking for a way to do it with just the container.

Comment: I understand your options are limited. If you want to follow this approach, you might accomplish rewriting in Tomcat itself, as described in 
[URLRewrite in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873406), referencing [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite) or, when using Tomcat 8, the [rewrite Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html).

Answer (score 0):

The thing you describe is not exactly compatible with the logic of Servlets.

If you want to use a service/library from 2 different applications in Tomcat, then you can add a library as shared library in Tomcat. Then, you will be able to use this library from your application servlets. If you want to achieve this, you will have to add the jar in `$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib` and then edit `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties` to add `{catalina.home}/mylibs/*.jar` in `common.loader` property. Then, you will be able to use your library in the various servlets of your applications.

However, this is different to what you describe. In fact, what you describe is infeasible in Tomcat, since each web application has its own ApplicationContext. Thus, **webappA**'s Application context will be http://host/webappA and **webappB**'s application context will be http://host/webappB. So, if you want to have a servlet outside those 2 applications, then this servlet will belong to a different ApplicationContext. So, it won't be possible to access this servlet through either of paths http://host/webappA/common, http://host/webappB/common, that belong to the previous ApplicationContexts.

Comment: Thanks.  I am familiar with common.loader, but Is there a way to load a "shared" servlet?  I was thinking it would be possible since the urlPatterns are relative to the webapp's context root, and I was hoping that it would be loaded into each webapp's ApplicationContext.  Using the provided servlet as an example: http://host/webappA/HelloServlet and http://host/webappB/HelloServlet.  What am I missing?

Comment: That's what I previously described. The only way to do this is by adding the servlet in both applications (so that it is accessible inside their contexts). The only way to "share" its functionality is by adding it as a shared library-jar and using it this way from your applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [war overlay](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html).