# Rewriting URL with Tomcat7

Tags: apache, tomcat, url, url-rewriting

I have deployed a single app on tomcat. Now i added a part in the url to identify a "special"version off my app

```
www.myUrl.com
www.myUrl.com/app1
```

Now I published 2 domains

```
www.myExternalUrl.com
www.myExternalUrl2.com
```

Each of this urls should point to a single app on tomcat but my users should we only myExternalUrl or myExternalUrl2

```
www.myExternalUrl.com -> www.myUrl.com
www.myExternalUrl2.com -> www.myUrl.com/app1
```

How can I do this on Tomcat?
Can I do this on Tomcat or I need another system like Apache to do this things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873406/urlrewrite-in-tomcat-7

Comment: thanks ... i think you are right